# how to get firebase.database.Reference full path

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

consider

```
var adaRef = firebase.database().ref("users/ada");
```

How can I get the full path of ref ? that is "users/ada" ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's surprisingly simple:

```
adaRef.toString()
```

Will print the full URL: `https://<your-app>firebaseio.com/users/ada`

So to just get the path, you substring it out of there. Two ways of doing that are:

```
adaRef.toString().substring(firebase.database().ref().toString().length-1)
```

or:

```
adaRef.toString().substring(adaRef.root.toString().length-1)
```

both will print `/users/ada`

Comment: I think you have a typo in the first sample -> firebase.()

Comment: Thanks. Fixed. Feel free to edit next time, I won't feel offended. :-)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen At least as of today, length() - 1 leads to the creation of a new node by the name 'm'. So, using only length() would suffice.

Answer (score 3):

**Deprecated from Version 9+**

On new versions of the framework you could use:

`snapshot.ref.path.toString()`

being `snapshot` the result of a call on a `Database Reference`.

Maybe this can be helpful.

Comment: This answer is no longer valid, because they deprecated the path property in version 9+ of the node SDK

Comment: @vIceBerg Thanks, I edited the answer to show the deprecation warning.

Answer (score 0):

Following on Frank's answer I extended firebase as follows:

```
firebase.database.Reference.prototype.fullkey = function() {
    return this.toString().substring(this.root.toString().length-1);
}
```

then you can do
 `adaRef.fullkey() // returns /users/ada`

(I would like to call this 'path' but that seems to be reserved by FB)