# How can I retrieve the full path to a child node using orderByChild equalTo?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to retrieve the full path to a Child node from a firebase query with orderByChild .equalTo? I have .indexOn: "city"

My data is structured as such:

[image: firebase structure]

I have tried:

```
firebase.database().ref('users').orderByChild('city').equalTo('calgary').once("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.ref.toString());
});
```

I have also tried:

```
console.log(snapshot.ref.toString());
//outputs: https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/users <-- WRONG, not full path.

console.log(snapshot.ref.path.toString());
//outputs /users <-- WRONG, not full path.
```

How can I get the full path - working up from the found key?
Expected:  /users/uid/location/

Comment: I don't feel like this should be marked as a duplicate because I'm trying to get it from orderByChild(), not just a simple ref.

Comment: Just for anyone coming to this "answer" in the future - This was not solved with Frank's solution below, but I found his response on a different question in which he replies ---  "The Firebase API only allows you to filter children one level deep (or with a known path) with its orderByChild and equalTo methods."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the full qualified URL for data, you can call [`DatabaseReference.toString()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#to-string).

To just get the path to that same data, you can substract the root path from the full path:

```
snapshot.ref.toString().substring(snapshot.ref.root.toString().length - 1)
```

Also see: [how to get firebase.database.Reference full path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37872478/how-to-get-firebase-database-reference-full-path), which I'm going to mark your question as a duplicate off.

---

Since you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

You need to loop over those results, and *then* can get the path to each individual node:

```
firebase.database.ref('users').orderByChild('city').equalTo('calgary').once("value", function(snapshot) {
  var rootPath = snapshot.ref.root.toString();
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    console.log(child.ref.toString().substring(rootPath.length - 1));
  })
});
```

---

It turns out your search is wrong. Since you're trying to order/filter on `location/city`, that's what you should also user in `orderByChild()`:

```
firebase.database().ref('users').orderByChild('location/city').equalTo('calgary')
```

Comment: You can just call `toString()` on any `DatabaseReference`, such as `snapshot.ref` in your code. I added an example of how to do that on query results.

Comment: Hey Frank, appreciate your help, but it still doesn't work for me. When executing, the forEach doesn't fire. (I added some more console.log(s) to check if it was entering the forEach).

Comment: Is there a "maximum" depth that data can be nested and searched in this way? It works if I remove location, and instead nest city:calgary directly under the UID.  But not with UID/location/city:calgary

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. Added a section on how to filter by nested properties. It'd likely have spotted that sooner, if your question didn't focus on finding the path of the node.

Comment: Makes sense now, appreciate your help! :) I'm coming from SQL so learning this stuff is taking a little bit longer than usual, haha.  Thanks again.