# Get path property of a reference

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

In the latest Node.js Admin SDK version, the `path` property of an `admin.database.Reference` is deprecated.
I need to know the path and looks like soon I won't be able to use it. And they don't provide any new method to call so I'm wondering if I missed something, how I could get that path.

I can always do a `ref.toString()` and remove the base URL but I feel it might be more a hack than a proper solution. Any advice?

Comment: I think the only solution is indeed to extract it from `ref.toString()` as you mentioned in your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37872478/how-to-get-firebase-database-reference-full-path. Can you share the code of your Cloud Function? There might be some other ways, in particular if you are looking for the path of the node which triggered the CF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at this [pull request](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/pull/830) on the Admin SDK open-source repo, it looks like the `path` property was deprecated to create type compatibility between the JavaScript/web SDK and the Node.js Admin SDK.

The client-side JavaScript SDK for Firebase Realtime Database never had a `path` property. The way to get the path has always been to call `toString()` explicitly, or to include the reference in a string concatenation. So it's not a hack, but the longstanding way to accomplish what you want.

Also see:

- [how to get firebase.database.Reference full path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37872478/how-to-get-firebase-database-reference-full-path)